# HTML CSS Loop Assistance

Tags: html, css

Hope you can help. I'm wondering if you can make the following type in a loop:

Do you know if this is possible?

```css
body {
  background: #000;
}

/* DEMO-SPECIFIC STYLES */
.typewriter h1 {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Bebas Neue;
  overflow: hidden; /* Ensures the content is not revealed until the animation */
  border-right: .15em solid orange; /* The typwriter cursor */
  white-space: nowrap; /* Keeps the content on a single line */
  margin: 0 auto; /* Gives that scrolling effect as the typing happens */
  letter-spacing: .15em; /* Adjust as needed */
  animation: 
    typing 3.5s steps(30, end),
    blink-caret .5s step-end infinite;
}

/* The typing effect */
@keyframes typing {
  from { width: 0 }
  to { width: 100% }
}

/* The typewriter cursor effect */
@keyframes blink-caret {
  from, to { border-color: transparent }
  50% { border-color: orange }
}
```

```html
<div class="typewriter">
  <h1><h1 class="m-size-54 text-align-left size-80">
  <span class="m-font-size-54 font-size-80" m-font-size-set="true" style="font-style: italic; font-family: 'Bebas Neue'; color: rgb(255, 255, 255); display: initial;" no_space_b="true" no_space_e="true">
      Hello World!</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm wondering if you can make the following type in a loop

Yes you can by just adding the `infinite` property to your `animation` shorthand just like you did with the animation of the `blink-caret`.

```css
body {
  background: #000;
}

/* DEMO-SPECIFIC STYLES */
.typewriter h1 {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Bebas Neue;
  overflow: hidden; /* Ensures the content is not revealed until the animation */
  border-right: .15em solid orange; /* The typwriter cursor */
  white-space: nowrap; /* Keeps the content on a single line */
  margin: 0 auto; /* Gives that scrolling effect as the typing happens */
  letter-spacing: .15em; /* Adjust as needed */
  animation: 
    typing 3.5s steps(30, end) infinite,
    /*                           ^--- ADDED THIS */
    blink-caret .5s step-end infinite;
}

/* The typing effect */
@keyframes typing {
  from { width: 0 }
  to { width: 100% }
}

/* The typewriter cursor effect */
@keyframes blink-caret {
  from, to { border-color: transparent }
  50% { border-color: orange }
}
```

```html
<div class="typewriter">
  <h1><h1 class="m-size-54 text-align-left size-80">
  <span class="m-font-size-54 font-size-80" m-font-size-set="true" style="font-style: italic; font-family: 'Bebas Neue'; color: rgb(255, 255, 255); display: initial;" no_space_b="true" no_space_e="true">
      Hello World!</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Dominik, 

That's perfect. Thank you so much! One more thing and we can leave it with an upvote.

Do you know how to give it a 3-5 second pause once the text has been written and then loops?

Comment: He answered you original question and should be upvoted regardless. To answer your next question, since animation delay only acts on the initial play you’ll want to change the keyframes and duration. 
`typing 5.5s steps(30, end) infinite`
`@keyframes typing {
  0% { width: 0; }
  25% { width: 100%; }
  100% {width: 100%; }
}`

Answer (score 0):

You can try like below. Adjust the width to fit the content and apply the animation on max-width instead. To add some delay make the last state of the keyframe end earlier.

```css
body {
  background: #000;
}

/* DEMO-SPECIFIC STYLES */
.typewriter h1 {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Bebas Neue;
  width:fit-content;
  overflow: hidden; /* Ensures the content is not revealed until the animation */
  border-right: .15em solid orange; /* The typwriter cursor */
  white-space: nowrap; /* Keeps the content on a single line */
  margin: 0 auto; /* Gives that scrolling effect as the typing happens */
  letter-spacing: .15em; /* Adjust as needed */
  animation: 
    typing 3.5s steps(30, end) infinite,
    blink-caret .5s step-end infinite;
}

/* The typing effect */
@keyframes typing {
  0% { max-width: 0 }
  70%,100% { max-width: 100% }
}

/* The typewriter cursor effect */
@keyframes blink-caret {
  from, to { border-color: transparent }
  50% { border-color: orange }
}
```

```html
<div class="typewriter">
  <h1 class="m-size-54 text-align-left size-80">
  <span class="m-font-size-54 font-size-80" m-font-size-set="true" style="font-style: italic; font-family: 'Bebas Neue'; color: rgb(255, 255, 255); display: initial;" no_space_b="true" no_space_e="true">
      Hello World!</span></h1>
</div>
```